# How to inherit gitlab variables accross projects?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I let gitlab fill a global variable with from CI/CD secret, and then inherit this global variable in other projects?

`templates/commons.yml`:

```
variables:
  TEST_VAR: $FILLED_FROM_SECRETS
```

`project/.gitlab_ci.yml`.

```
include:
  - project: '/templates'
    ref: master
    file:
      - 'commons.yml'

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $TEST_VAR
```

Result: the variable is never set. Why?
(of course the `FILLED_FORM_SECRETS` variable is set in the commons project)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that `include:` only brings in the contents on the YAML file, not the project level settings or variables.

As possible alternatives, you can:

- Set the variable in the template directly (not recommended for sensitive values)
- Set variables set on your own self-hosted runners (note variables cannot be masked this way)
- Set [instance CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/instance_level_ci_variables.html)
- Set a [required CI configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/continuous_integration.html#required-pipeline-configuration) to forcibly include a template to all projects (that template can include variables you need) (note variables cannot be masked this way)
- Set group CI/CD variables (where all your projects live under the common group)
- [Retrieve your secrets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/) using the vault integration or as part of your job script

Answer (score 1):

With the [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) keyword the included files are merged with the `.gitlab-ci.yml` and then your `.gitlab-ci.yml` is executed in the repo where the pipeline is triggered. Therefore, only gobal variables in this repo or inherited variables from any parent groups are known. That's why `TEST_VAR` is not substituted with the value from the secret as the variable is defined in another repository.

Comment: And there is no chance to work around that (beside moving all projects under a "common" group)?

Comment: This is a nice explanation which answers the "Why?" part of the question, but not the first part: "How can I let gitlab fill a global variable with from CI/CD secret, and then inherit this global variable in other projects?"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#include-an-array-of-configuration-files), the syntax you used require you provide the whole path for your project (all the part after gitlab.com/group/project).

Assuming your project path is gitlab.com/group/my_project, then you choose one of the following

```
include:
  - project: 'group/my_project'
    ref: master
    file:
      - 'templates/commons.yml'
# or simply, if 'templates' folder lives in the same project as your gitlab-ci.yml file
  - '/templates/commons.yml'

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $TEST_VAR
```

I personally used both ways in my work, but the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#include-an-array-of-configuration-files) shows other ways to implement this that you can have a look at.

Comment: `template` is already my "commons" gitlab project name. there is no subfolder, thus access with `file: commons.yml` should be fine, isn't it? The problem here seems to be that the `$FILLED_FROM_SECRETS` variable is defined on the `template` project, thus not the project where the pipeline runs. And somewhat those secrets cannot be resolved??

Comment: Try removing the leading slash then... `project: templates`